# Pre-Bridge Handlers Asterisk playback issue

Tags: asterisk

Hi i am using pre bridge handler U to play an audio when call is answered by the called party however caller is also able to hear the playback is there anyway possible so that only called party can hear that sound?`

```
 same => n(agentreq),Set(LIMIT_CONNECT_FILE=playbackfile)
same => n,Set(LIMIT_PLAYAUDIO_CALLER=no) ;check no
    same => n,Set(LIMIT_PLAYAUDIO_CALLEE=yes)
same => n,UserEvent(CallEnteringConference, Channel:${CHANNEL}, Agent:${TARGET_AGENT}, DialedPhoneNumber:${DialedPhoneNumber})
same => n,GotoIf($["${${TARGET_AGENT}IsBeingSpied}" == "1"]?spyhangup:request)
    same => n(spyhangup),SoftHangup(${${TARGET_AGENT}ChannelName})
 same => n,Set(GLOBAL(${TARGET_AGENT}ChannelName)=0)
    same => n,Set(CHANNEL(hangup_handler_push)=agent-request-coach-generate,${TARGET_AGENT},1)
    same => n(request),Dial(Local/${TARGET_AGENT}@agent-request,,m(default)L(${MILLI_SECONDS_IN_DAY}:1:1)U(testsound))
    same => n,Hangup()


[testsound]
exten => s,1,NoOp()
    same=> n,Playback(en/beep)
same=> n,Return()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't found flag in dial options help(for example M always was ok), you always can just use chanspy to one party.